# How to avoid recreation of a linked container with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following in my docker-compose.yml:

```
  service_1:
    container_name:<some_name>
    ...
    ...
  service_2:
    container_name:<some_name>
    ...
    links:
      - service_1
```

When I rebuild an image with changes for service_1 and execute `docker-compose up -d` it's expected that service_1 container being re-created (lets assume that containers for both services are running at the moment of command execution). But container for service_2 is re-created too and it's also expected.

My question is how to **avoid** a recreation of service_2's container (despite the link) in this situation?

Comment: how about using the `--no-deps` flag along with `--no-recreate`?

Comment: @meatspace, --no-recreate flag will cause to no recreation of service_1 at all...

Comment: Won't it create the nonexistent service_1 container, and _not_ recreate the service_2 container (since it exists already?)

Comment: @meatspace , in my case service_1 is already running